# Пунктуация при определении с предлогом "с"

Tags: пунктуация, определения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно расставить знаки препинания в следующих предложениях. Они изменены, но сути это не меняет.

1. И вот он здесь () со старым портфелем в руках () стоит на пороге кабинета.

Признаться, теряюсь в этом предложении, поэтому знаки расставлены скорее интуитивно.

И вот он здесь, со старым портфелем в руках стоит на пороге кабинета.

И вот он здесь: со старым портфелем в руках стоит на пороге кабинета.

Какой из них верный? Или должно быть вообще как-то по-другому?

2. Две женщины () в своих нелепых белых шляпках с цветами по бокам () громко обсуждают недавнее событие.

Две женщины () с милыми собачками в руках, что были куплены недавно, громко обсуждают вчерашнюю встречу.

Склоняюсь к тому, что нигде запятые не нужны, но не уверена. Буду рада, если вы поможете. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы уверены, что предложение такое (так у Sharon)? *И вот он здесь стоит на пороге кабинета.* Не случайно же вы поставили эту запятую. Чего вы её поставили?

Comment: Просто так странно (*здесь стоит на пороге*). Гораздо естественнее это: *И вот он [уже] здесь [находится], [а именно] со старым портфелем в руках [он] стоит на пороге кабинета.* По поставленной вами запятой мне показалось, что вы хотели этого.

Comment: Прошу прощения, удалила свое сообщение, решив, что, возможно, просто устала и стоит перечитать ваше сообщение завтра.

Comment: Случайно отправила. еще не дописала.

Comment: Ничего, оно и без того сообщения к месту. Думал, что вы знаете, что оборот либо не обособляется, либо обособляется с двух сторон (а не с одной). Поэтому решил, что та запятая неспроста (для БСП).

Comment: Полностью исправляю ответ. Тогда было бы логичнее использовать тире (или двоеточие?), разве нет? Он находится здесь, а дальше пояснение, где именно и при каких обстоятельствах. Словно представляем человека. Смотрю похожие примеры на сайтах, и какие только знаки не используются. 


"Он вот он здесь - стоит на пороге с портфелем"?

По ощущениям, в оригинальном предложении после "с портфелем руках" должна стоять запятая. Если бы конструкция была после глагола, то точно нет. А вот если до него, да еще и с зависимым словом... Кажется, для меня это слишком сложно.

Comment: Все абзацы съелись. Потрясающе.

Comment: Иногда предложу что-нибудь и только спустя время понимаю, что ошиблась или просто не досмотрела.

Comment: Если тире, то интонационное — для подчёркивания. Но подчёркивать нет надобности. Если обычное, то в простом предложении: *И вот он здесь — на пороге кабинета.* Двоеточие не в тему. Почему? Рассказывать о том, где он находится? Нет, это и так понятно. Раз используем местоимение "здесь", то читающий в курсе, где это. При двоеточии рассказывают о чём-то неизвестном (а не дополняют известное). Запятая лучше всего.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Правильно: *И вот он здесь, **со старым портфелем в руках**, стоит на пороге кабинета.*

**Пояснение**

Обособлено **несогласованное определение** "со старым портфелем в руках", которое относится и к подлежащему "он", и к сказуемому "стоит" (двунаправленная связь).

Определение, отнесенное **к личному местоимению**,обособляется всегда, а здесь оно  находится **на расстоянии** (дополнительный повод для обособления).

2. *Две женщины, ***в своих нелепых белых шляпках с цветами по бокам***, громко обсуждают недавнее событие.*

*Две женщины, **с милыми собачками в руках, что были куплены недавно**, громко обсуждают вчерашнюю встречу.*

В этих предложениях также обособлено **распространенное** несогласованное определение.

**Примечание**.

Оборот "***в своих нелепых белых шляпках с цветами по бокам***" также включает два определения (согласованное и несогласованное), но второе определение (с цветами по бокам) не обособляется. Это основной (отличительный), а не уточняющий признак для существительного "в шляпках".

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутые ответы! :)

Answer (score 1):

Более вероятен и удачен вариант с БСП:
*И вот он здесь, со старым портфелем в руках [он] стоит на пороге кабинета.*

"Своих" избыточно, и так понятно, что то их шляпки. Можно и без запятых:
*Две женщины в нелепых белых шляпках громко обсуждают недавнее событие.

Две женщины в нелепых белых шляпках с цветами по бокам громко обсуждают недавнее событие.*

Тоже можно без обособления, но лучше с запятой (а то вдруг фантастика, и обсуждают с собачками):
*Две женщины, с милыми собачками в руках, что были куплены недавно, громко обсуждают вчерашнюю встречу.*

Comment: Непонятна грамматика первого предложении  - это БСП? И это вы называете удачным вариантом?Стиль футуристический.  Обособление несогласованных определений во многом зависит от распространенности предложения и определения, поэтому менять в тексте ничего не нужно.

Comment: Да ладно! *И вот он [уже] здесь. Со старым портфелем в руках стоит на пороге кабинета.* Что плохого? Если простое предложение, то получается: *здесь стоит на пороге кабинета*. Это как? Здесь стоит или же на пороге? Вы об этом подумали?

Comment: Такое чувство, будто у Вас какие-то свои правила и видение ситуации. Уже который вопрос подряд:D

Comment: oleedd, не надо заниматься "расчлененкой", это не есть хорошо.  Предложение в заданном варианте выглядит и воспринимается вполне гармонично, а вы делите его на части. Зачем?

Comment: @Лиза Свои правила? А вам указали на правило о том, что запятые обязательны? Нет такого правила! Хотел вам помочь и сказать правду, а нет, вам правда не нужна.

Comment: @Sharon Потому что "*здесь стоит на пороге*" — это не грамотно. Стоит определиться: здесь стоит или на пороге? Или же сделать уточнение: *здесь стоит, [а именно] на пороге кабинета*. Вот это по правилам.

Comment: oleedd, я могу согласиться с вами, что здесь используется не совсем стандартный  (отчасти авторский) вариант грамматики. Мне он кажется достаточно  художественным. Но вы-то что хотите, отменить его, использовать стандарт? Ну попробуйте перестроить предложение полностью,  используя ту же лексику и семантику. А мы сравним два варианта и дадим им оценку. Только сами не запутайтесь:  различить необособленный оборот в составе сказуемого и просто обособленный оборот в этой теме не так просто. Иногда достаточно изменить порядок слов, и решение будет другим.

Comment: Он не художественный, а очень разговорный (это в прямом смысле характерно для разговорного стиля), поэтому мне показалось, что здесь другое имеется в виду (БСП). А что перестраивать, просто "здесь" убрать. Не, этот оборот не может входить в сказуемое, так как глагол выражает нужный смысл и без него.

Comment: Ваш вариант в студию,  а иначе нет смысла разговаривать. Уклоняетесь, однако, одни слова (что да как).  Вот и теряется всякое доверие к вам.  А тему, про которую я говорила,  вы не знаете, вроде как первый раз слышите. Розенталя хотя бы почитайте.

Comment: Не знаю, что вы хотите. Как перестроить? Вы не говорите, что именно нужно, к чему эти претензии? Просто повыделываться в отместку? Вот: *И вот он со старым портфелем в руках стоит на пороге кабинета.* Какой параграф и пункт у Розенталя? Что-то вы путаете.

Comment: В качестВе ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЯ.  "И вот он со старым портфелем в руках стоит на пороге кабинета". Без обособления предложение выглядит неестественно,  Это не интонация простого предложения, если вы еще разбираетесь в этом.  Как его разделить на тему и рему, или на две фразы?  И авторское наречие "здесь" потеряли.  И по поводу темы. Посмотрите материал по согласованным определениям  Пункт 2 (3) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108  То же самое можно сказать о несогласованных определениях.  Счастливого вам прочтения и глубокого понимания!

Comment: Там оборот как вставка, здесь можно и без этого.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь не всё так просто.

Если оборот поясняет, какие именно женщины (среди толпы), то запятые не нужны:
*Женщина в белой шляпке вышла вперёд.*
Но эту информацию иногда можно дать уточнением (тогда паузы). Когда оборот длинный, это актуально.

А если и без оборота ясно, что то за женщины, то надо обособить. В примерах Розенталя везде имена (пояснение не требуется), поэтому там везде запятые.

В английском языке этот принцип используется даже для придаточных. А в русском нельзя понять по пунктуации, придаточное уточняет или же даёт дополнительную информацию.