# Обособление обстоятельства запятыми

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация, дополнение

*Сама палата, с ее высокими потолками, казалась при этом свете узким и душным закоулком.*

(«Жили-были», Леонид Андреев)

Здравствуйте. Скажите, пожалуйста, почему обособляется дополнение "с ее высокими потолками"?

Comment: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уточняющее определение — *с её высокими потолками* — член предложения, следующий за уточняемым. Такое определение выделяется запятыми.

> Длинная, [*какая именно?*] в несколько вёрст, тень ложилась от гор на степи (Толстой).

Comment: У Толстого нет уточнения. Одно определение не уточняет другое, "сама" не нуждается в конкретизации и не может быть конкретизировано. Так не получается: *Сама, [какая именно?] с ее высокими потолками, палата казалась...*

Comment: "Сама" — определительное местоимение, оно, указывая на уточняемое, его не подменяет.

Comment: "Сама" используется, когда уже известно, что за предмет. Нельзя такое уточнить. Сравнить: *Та палата, что с ее высокими потолками, казалась...*